# Multiple key press simultaneously for Windows logo key + Alt + PrtScn in powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-ise, pester

I tried the below code by referred the link but not able to press those keys at a time.

Do I need any change?

```
$code = @'
namespace SendTheKeys {
  class SendIt {
   public static void Main(string[] args) {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

        private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
        private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

        public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
        {
            keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
        }

        public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
        {
            keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        }
  }
 }
}
'@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -ReferencedAssemblies "System.Windows.Forms"
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("LWin")
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("Alt") 
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("PrintScreen")
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyUp("LWin") 
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyUp("Alt")
```

Comment: That's quite hard. Suggesting to use InputSimulator

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this code: https://github.com/stefanstranger/PowerShell/blob/master/WinKeys.ps1

I assume you should be able to use the function "Win" like `Win "%{PRTSC}"` to get what you want

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already resolve this but try to Change the "Alt" as "LMenu" (If you want to press the Left ALT key) `[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("LMenu")`
and you should KeyUp all the key that has been pressed.

```
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("LWin")
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("LMenu") 
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("PrintScreen")
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyUp("PrintScreen")
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyUp("LMenu") 
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyUp("LWin")
```

Kindly refer to this link for the key codes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes